# Set null value to an int variable in database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I created my database with entity framework - code first.

```
public class Customer:BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string VerPassword { get; set; }
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
    public int RolId { get; set; }
    public int QR { get; set; }
}
```

I have a working registration page but know I added QR part which is integer. I do not want to user give any input for this and I want it to be NULL in the database.

I set all of the datas to database with this design pattern

```
_customerService.Add(model);
```

I tried to set null to QR column like this but it does not work

```
int? value = 0;

if (value == 0)
{
    value = null;
}
model.QR = value;
```

The error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

What can I do to set null value to QR column

Comment: Change the type of `QR` to `int?`.  Otherwise you'll end up with `QR` being `not null` in your DB.

Answer (score 3):

> What can I do to set null value to QR column

`int` does not allow `null`'s, so you need to change `QR` type to be a nullable `int` (i.e. `int?` or `Nullable<int>`):

```
public class Customer:BaseEntity
{
    // ...
    public int? QR { get; set; }
}
```

Read more:

- [Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)